# MongoDB: How to get add filter main collection by second collection using $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, lookup

I have a company collection which looks like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a897da6dffe7eb1a3028863"),

    "name" : "ABC",

    "website" : "http://www.abc.af",
    "alternativeEmail" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "address" : "Floor 1, Street 6",
    "type" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5a897c81dffe7eb1a302885d"),
        "name" : "Company / Corporation"
    },
    "createdBy" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5a897a21739589bbf635c9b4"),
        "firstName" : "Admin",
        "lastName" : "Admin"
    },
    "status" : 1,
    "socialLinks" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

another collection `companyType` which has records like.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a897c81dffe7eb1a302885d"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-20T05:16:09.503Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-18T13:15:45.624Z"),
    "name_en" : "Company / Corporation",
    "name_da" : "Company / Corporation",
    "name_pa" : "Company / Corporation",
    "validPlans" : {
        "planId" : ObjectId("5a897b58dffe7eb1a3028858"),
        "planName" : "Company / Corporation",
        "billingType" : "Prepaid"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}.
```

Now, what I want is to filter company which `companyType.validPlan.billingType === 'prePaid'` where `company.type.id = companyType._id`.

I have written my query like this.

```
db.getCollection('companies').aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
    "from": "companytypes",
    "localField": "type.id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "companyType"    
    }
 }
]);
```

I am not sure if it is the solution because I can not filter by `companyType.validPlan.billingType ==='prePaid'`.

So how can I achieve it?

Comment: Why not? Surely you can filter by `billingType`.

Comment: Add `{$unwind:"$companyType"}, {$match:{"companyType.validPlan.billingType":"prePaid"}}` after `$lookup`

Comment: db.getCollection('companies').aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
    "from": "companytypes",
    "localField": "type.id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "companyType"    
    },
 },
 {
    $unwind:"$companyType"
 },
 {
    $match:
        {
            "$companyType.validPlan.billingType":"Prepaid"
        }
  }
]); does not work.

Comment: You have $ in match stage. should just be  `{ $match: { "companyType.validPlan.billingType":"Prepaid" } }`

Comment: Thanks, it works by now